# Can I extend the the antenna of a magnetron with a cable?

Tags: rf, antenna, magnetron

If I connect a piece of heavy copper wire or copper rod to the antenna cap of a magnetron can I guide the current so that microwaves would be emitted further away?

[image]

Comment: Which current are you talking about?

Comment: @Andyaka I  am talking about the 2.54GHz alternative current emitted by the tip of the magnetron

Answer (score 11):

Please don't play with magnetrons.

If somebody who knows what they are doing adds a properly matched waveguide to the output of a magnetron, they will be able to guide the energy further away.

If you have to ask, then you don't know what you're doing. Please don't play with magnetrons.

The output power of a magnetron is quite sufficient to cook the corneas of your eyes in moments, rendering you blind. I mention these parts of your anatomy specifically as they are not cooled by blood flow, and don't have nerves that could warn you by feeling warm. You could probably get away with temporary modest heating on the skin of an arm or hand without permanent damage.

If you use an improperly matched waveguide, then you could cause standing waves which could damage the magnetron, or burn or electrocute you.

The power supply to a magnetron is extremely dangerous. It's high enough voltage to jump through dry clothing (unlike mains), and it's high enough current to kill you in moments (unlike a neon sign transformer or burner igniter).

Please don't play with magnetrons.

Perhaps the most important answer to your question is that the output stub of a magnetron is **designed** to be inserted into a waveguide. The most practical way to drive coax with it would be to use a length of waveguide between the magnetron and a coax stub of appropriate length inserted into the guide.

Comment: +1. Could you please embolden, or make the text red, or similar, for the part with the damage to one's self (the eyes)? Anything that can be extremely dangerous to health should really stand out.

Comment: I already played enough with magnetron to know that my face would feel the heat, and that there really is no reason for me to look at  the magnetron when it's running considering I already built a stainless steel oven for it to go into. 
About the waveguiguides for microwaves they are usually made of rectangular section 6x3cm, what's im trying to build here is a "solid" waveguide, that is no guiding EM waves but merely AC from the magnetron

Comment: @ManudeHanoi You appear to have drawn a coaxial cable onto the magnetron, which (up to a point) is a valid alternative to the hollow tube for guiding the EM waves from the magnetron. The trick will be hoping that the current density on the surface of the inner conductor is low enough not to overheat, and the voltage across the dielectric low enough not to spark. Failure to match it well will exacerbate those two issues. Hollow box is so much more forgiving on all three aspects.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen do feel free to add your own answer in bold block caps if you feel the warnings need more emphasis.

Comment: I already met sparking to the ground in previous builds. Following your advice, I'll check with the skin effect parameters at 2,4ghz, but I didnt expect it  considering i'll be generous with copper and considering the existing antennas of magnetrons are already very thin. You forgot to warn me about the berylium oxide insulator poisonning btw.

Comment: yes I believe coax is the best to prevent unwanted radiation losses before reaching the tip of the antenna, is that correct ?

Comment: You mentionned coax is valid "up to a point" can't you clarify what point ?

Comment: of yes, skin effect very strong at 2.4ghz, I'll need a big diameter, or maybe a flat bar shape instead of a cylinder shape for the conductor, my purpose what to guide the energy using something smaller  than the usual 6x3cm

Comment: @Neil_UK A hazard to one's health should be emphasized to stand out, showing that it has a (much) greater weight than the rest of the words. There's a reason why such warnings have very distinctive signs and colours: to make sure users see them first and that the users will (hopefully) end up cautious. As it is, the part with the health hazard doesn't differ much from the rest of the text. In fact, the only part that stands out is the "designed" word; hardly harmful. My comment was not meant as a critique ("+1"), or as imposing ("could you please") -- it was meant for all the future readers.

Comment: When the cross-sectional dimensions of the thing conducting power from the magnetron gets to be a substantial fraction of a wavelength of it's emission, **there is no "merely AC from the magnetron"**.  Yes, there is "AC from the magnetron", but there's no "merely", and doing your design in terms of guiding EM waves _is_ the simple solution.  And, in order to conduct that much power, your means of conducting the power _must_ be a substantial fraction of a wavelength.  So, for your problem, there is no "merely AC from the magnetron".

Answer (score 2):

Connecting a microwave signal to a transmission line is possible as radar and radio link makers have shown. Doing it so that something really is carried by the line needs a transmission line which can handle the wanted power without arcing nor attenuating the signal to useless. Waveguides are good for this but you need one which has diameter several centimeters to make about 2,5GHz possible to propagate. Coax can be used at short distances, say 0.5 meters. But it will dissipate  easily so much that one with plastic insulator melts.

Another problem is to make the connection to the transmission line work. The fields of the wave must fit (as space vector fields) exactly to a possible spatial waveform in the line.Otherwise the signal doesn't jump to the line. The need of knowledge what radiowave is and how it behaves is somehow high when compared to what's needed to make a mains AC connection to work.

Of course, there's a possibility that you have some incredible luck and you get the radiowave out properly without any radio engineering knowledge nor making proper circuit measurements with low power instruments.

**As others have already mentioned**, you'll need luck even more to stay alive and without getting blind or otherwise badly damaged. Kilovolts from magnetron's power supply are well worth an electric chair and microwaves can fry your eyes and other maybe still needed parts of you faster than you can think(even before your brain is fried).

**My advice: Stop as long as it's your choice**.

Comment: Please keep in mind that I might possibly be wise enough not to lick the magnetron or its power supply when it's live. With that in mind, I don't understand your sentence " The fields of the wave must fit (as space vector fields) ... to make a mains AC connection to work." . There are 2 different problems, one is the EM wave emission from the new tip of the antenna, and one is the *electrical connection* from the new  antenna to the existing antenna and ground of the magnetron. You seem to imply that there are special constraints related to the latter, if so, could you elaborate on that ?

Comment: You should learn how a radiowave is put together of simultaneous perpendicular electric and magnetic fields. You should let the magnetron output to radiate into a cavity resonator which is designed to exactly fit to the directions of the fields of the wave coming out of the magnetron. The same resonator should have a catching stub or loop which catches the wave from the resonator to a coaxial cable (I guess you want to have coaxial output). The catcher must fit into the field directions in the resonator. Designing all these things properly needs 3 years of radio engineering studies.

Comment: @ManudeHanoi All the questions and answers on this site remain for anyone in the future to read. Since people that come afterwards will not have been here to see the discussion from the beginning, they will not know to assume anything about anyone's level of expertise. Therefore, any warnings you see (actually, everything written in here) will be read with a blank mind by any future readers. It's to these that warnings and such are addressed to, mostly. So, don't take it personal, it's meant to prevent accidents in general, not in particular.

Comment: @user287001 why bother catching catching waves when I can make a direct electrical contact with the magnetron stub (as shown in the graphic)?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen the warnings are useful (explaining the risks), the gatekeeping (infering on the ability of the reader) is not.

Comment: @ManudeHanoi there's no such option as making direct contact which connects the voltage and current somehow directly instead of using any waves.  The wavelength is so short that a 1cm long piece of wire must be designed as a transmission line to make it work. The voltage between wires and current are absolutely too poor simplifications. The power does not flow in the metal, it's as a wave in the space outside the metal. The metal is needed only to create the boundary conditions which force the wave to propagate to the wanted direction. In coax the wave is in the insulator layer.

Comment: @user287001 well...however difficult this connection  might be, it has to be easier to make than capturing waves from a chamber as you mentionned earlier (with all the nasty heating and impedance issues) right ? BTW the antenna of the commercial magnetron is just that, a piece of copper pipe...from the teardown images i've seen.

Comment: See the stub as a quarter wave whip antenna with a ground plane. I guess you want more directing antenna.  The stub probably would radiate well into a waveguide which is designed for 2,5GHz if you place it a quarter of wavelength off from the closed end of the W.G. .The other end can lead to a horn antenna. Or you can saw slits to the wavequide and use it as your antenna.  You can also build a Yagi with a ground plane. Do not expect these are possible to make to work only by guessing.

Comment: yes I already made a classic waveguide, and used the same parameters. But now I need a way to distribute the microwave with a smaller form factor and deliver them about 30 cm away at the heart of the food that needs to be cooked (that's why I want to use a wire). I dont need a more directing antenna (the opposite), I just need the source of the microwave to be at the heart of the food

Comment: please also have a look at another question I have on the topic :
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/696284/why-do-microwave-ovens-need-to-have-a-resonant-cavity/696516#696516

Comment: That IEEE paper you link to on that post refers is from 1970.  I think microwave oven designers have learned a few things since then :-)

Comment: Make a special food kettle which doesn't absorb too much microwaves (avoid beryllium oxide as the ceramic kettle material) and holds the radiating stub in the middle of the food. Keep the kettle and the magnetron inside a microwave proof metal case. That case should be designed to have a electric field standing wave maximum inside the food.